# How to check valid wsEngine on Engine.io (sockect.io)

Tags: socket.io, engine.io

I've set my Socket.io `wsEngine` option as `uWs` like [over here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1).

How can I check the valid `wsEngine` on `Socket.io`?

Because I want to be sure about that which socket engine is being run by `Socket.io` library?